# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design, launch

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389/design-for-bicycles-stack-exchange).

I have made a few tweaks on the design mockups I presented in the other post.

I decided not to go with the heart logo. I didn't think a headbadge would work as a logo at first due to the favicon size. But after I played around with the concept more, I think it works with some modification from the bigger version. I believe a headbadge is a more fitting logo. I still left a tiny heart in the logo, to show our love for bicycles, in a more subtle way.

I've also removed the street sign visual treatment for the selected top navigation links in the header. I'm using the sign treatment in several places on the site, I didn't want to over use it.

If you see any CSS bugs, please start a **new post** and tag it with [design](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug).

[image: Bicycles.se Logo]

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the following urls and do a hard browser refresh.

http://sstatic.net/bicycles/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/bicyclesmeta/img/favicon.ico

Congrats on the launch! Thank you for being an awesome community.

Comment: Will we get a matching theme for our blog?

Comment: @Ambo100 I have the blog theme converted. It should go out today.

Comment: @Ambo100 blog theme has been updated.

Comment: So far I've been finding it much more difficult (in comparison with the beta theme) to find questions on the front page that match one or more of my favourite tags. Could we perhaps change the colours highlighted to be more clear.

Comment: Any chance of making the system message a little more prominent? It's very easy to miss at the moment. (Center-aligning it would help, I think.)

Comment: @Neil sure i'll center align it. expect it in the next build.

Comment: @Jin - Great, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I keep flipping back and forth between meta and the main site and watching the cyclist turn around to go home at night. Amazing!

Comment: just noticed that as well, love it

Comment: Haha awesome effect... too bad lots of people will miss it... perhaps it could be time based on the main page that would be awesome!

Comment: Perhaps it would be safer if the meta biker had a white reflector in the front of his bike?

Comment: @Ambo - I think getting rid of the red point where the headlight is emitted would take care of that.

Comment: @Neil the red point is no more. you may have to refresh.

Answer (score 5):

Yay! No more beta! Happy days!

Answer (score 0):

@Jin: Not that it's a huge deal or anything, but the browser title (for me at least) still shows the beta icon.

I've checked Chrome, IE9, and Firefox 3, which are what are currently on my machine. I've done hard resets on Chrome and IE9.

Is it still in the source or is it my machine?

Comment: All my browsers are showing me the latest favicons. have you tried clearing cache?

Comment: Yes, I've cleared cache, restarted browsers, and tried running in private mode, too.  It's only the title icon by the URL. Not the page header or anything.