# What is the icon supposed to represent?

Tags: discussion, design

From looking at the small favicon, it looks like a bluegreen heart on top of a gray cube:

[image: Favicon "Favicon"]

Seeing the larger icon, it looks like a medieval shield or saloon doors with SE on them, or perhaps a cycloptic transformer head. What is this supposed to represent in relation to bicycles? Am I missing something?

[image: Logo "Logo"]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's intended to be a [head badge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_badge). A head badge is the decoration on the front of the head tube of a bicycle. Some head badges are simply paint, but others are raised decals or even metal. I believe this one is intended to represent more of a metallic 3-d head badge, with the color of the heart matching the background color to give an impression that it might be a cut-out, which is a common design element on head badges.

The original design idea had a heart logo with a bicycle in it:
[Design for Bicycles Stack Exchange.](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389/design-for-bicycles-stack-exchange)

However, some people didn't care for the heart logo. A [headbadge was suggested by zenbike](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/395) and others.

The final design had a headbadge with a heart in it: [New Design Launched](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/new-design-launched)

Here's a larger version:

[image]

Comment: Ah, now I see it. Sort of. The heart's sides are cut off so it sort of looks like a thick book. I'm not a huge fan of branding, so I usually removed anything on my headtubes and/or painted/herculined over them, so I have zero association between a head badge and a bicycle, but that's just me personally I suppose.

Comment: @Ehryk: Some bikes don't have head badges, too. It's not universal, but it seemed like something recognizable enough to most cyclists and the designer didn't want to go with bike parts.

Comment: Now that I was told, I see it like one now. I'd probably have went with [cranks](http://www.gettyicons.com/free-icons/124/mountain-bike/png/256/mountain_bike_crankset_256.png) or something similar.