# How do you feel about the icon used for this SE Bicycles site?

Tags: discussion, design

I think the icon is bland and it looks like a stock option.

[image: icon from the main site]

Can we have it changed? How do other people feel about this icon? I think it should be more bicycle-related.

Do you feel that this question is not worth considering?

This is my first question ever asked on SE and I'm excited to be a part of this community!

Ride on!

Comment: You mean just because it looks like a sergeant's chevron you think it isn't appropriate??  (I'd never really worried about it.  Now I won't be able to sleep tonight.)

Comment: Would you design a better/different one?

Comment: I completely agree. Why a bike itself or wheel was skipped who knows. Shame stackexchange snobbery has berated your question. Keep asking questions, it's what makes us human.

Comment: @Sam - It's not snobbery (thank you very much, mine is one of the close votes) it's just that the question of site design has been done to death here. But you're right about one thing: It never hurts to ask a question. That's why I spent time answering this anyway, to be welcoming to a new user.

Comment: @Sam - "Why a bike itself or wheel was skipped who knows." I think because both of those don't work as well when reduced to favicon size. Also because the bike and a wheel/rim are already in the design, in the header.

Comment: @Neil, I am biased to bike favicons I'm afraid, check my blog: blog.samt.st for a nice bike favicon :)

Comment: I think that wouldn't have worked along with the rest of the design theme here; bold colors and shapes are the order of the day.

Answer (score 7):

I for one like the icon.  It looks like something that any bike would proudly display on its head tube.

Comment: Sorry, I never noticed that was the bicycles specific logo for stack exchange, I identify nothing with it about bicycles. Only having seen this question and thought about it did I think it must be a brand badge type thing.

Answer (score 3):

> This is my first question ever asked on SE and I'm excited to be a part of this community!

Welcome! From your bio, it looks like you've done a good amount of cycling, and almost certainly would have something to contribute. I'd suggest that, rather than complaining about our logo (which the community has discussed already), you might contribute by asking and answering questions.

> How do other people feel about this icon? I think it should be more bicycle-related.

Personally, I think that using a headbadge to represent a bicycle site is a good move. It's related to bicycles, but simple. Logos have to be simple or they look bad.

> Can we have it changed?

That said, if you have a better idea for a logo, please propose it! It'd have to go through the Stack Exchange designers, though. And they won't make a change just for change's sake, it'd have to be a significant improvement to warrant changing the logo across the entire network. Tee-shirts and other merch would also need to be redesigned.

Answer (score 1):

People (including the designer) discussed the icon in comments to [this answer](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/395/1097) (and perhaps other places too).

Comment: I think those comments were mostly about the previous iteration of the design with a really big red heart.